# How can I see the version of Steam Deck?

Tags: steam-deck

I was thinking about buying a Steam Deck and to save a couple of bucks, figured I'd try to buy one used. Before I hand over the cash, I'd like to verify the one I'm buying is as advertised.

As there are three versions advertised (and perhaps varying generations (?)), is there a way I can determine the version—especially the storage distinction of the 64GB, 256GB, and 512GB models, based on the outward physical appearance or the internal menu—and if so, how?

I've found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hn9f6UG0svA&t=16s) demonstrating how to find the Serial Number within the System menu option. However, this video doesn't specifically contain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly check the storage from the menu, in Settings > Storage.

My 256gb model shows 226.8GB total.

[image: Steam deck storage]

As there are only 3 models, which all have different storage capacities, this would be a good indicator of the model.

Comment: Would this storage number be affected by SD cards?

Comment: No, that's internal storage. The card is shown separately. I will add a picture

Answer (score 1):

While Neon1024's answer shows you how to find the current storage capacity of your Steam Deck, it doesn't shows what the current version is (64/256/512GB for LCD and 256/512GB/1TB for OLED). Some people might upgrade their storage and/or change parts (for example, someone with a broken 512GB screen might replace it with the 64/256GB screen because is 30 dollars cheaper).

You can see here that my Steam Deck shows 256GB, but this is not a 256GB model:

[image]

If you go to Settings > System > Hardware > Model/Serial Numbers > Devices > Your Steam Deck Device, it will show you the parts that your Steam Deck came with, in this case, a 64GB eMMC module:

[image]

So far, the model numbers I could find for the SSDs are:

#### 64GB LCD

- Shenzhen Longsys Electronics FE2H0M064G-B5X10 [Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK8g6.png)

#### 256GB LCD/OLED

- Kingston OM3PDP3256B-A01 [Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/0/3716062978744826996/#c3716062978744957528)
- Transcend TS256GMTE352T-VLV [Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/0/3716062978744826996/#c3716062978744957528)

#### 512GB LCD/OLED

- Phison ESMP512GKB4C3-E13TS [Source](https://www.pcgamer.com/valve-has-quietly-downgraded-the-steam-deck-ssd-on-some-256gb-and-512gb-models/)
- Phison ESMP512GKB4C3-E08 [Source](https://www.pcgamer.com/valve-has-quietly-downgraded-the-steam-deck-ssd-on-some-256gb-and-512gb-models/)
- Kingston OM3PDP3512B-A01 [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/vndkny/comment/ie6yds9/)

#### 1TB OLED